# Predicate Logic Negating a WFF, do signs cancel?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, predicate-logic

I'm working through an example for my course and I'm wondering if signs need to be canceled for this negation to be correct.

The original question is as follows --

(∀x)P(x) Λ Q(x)(R(x)-->W(x))

I believe the correct negation of this is as follows -- 
(∃x)P'(x) v Q'(x)(R(x) v W'(x))

The question I have is, assuming I took the correct steps here, would the R's negation symbol cancel out since DeMorgan's law would be applied to turn the implication into a disjunction, then the outside negation symbol would distribute in on the R and W where the R would already have a negation symbol?

Comment: Your formulas are not well formed because there is no connective between $Q(x)$ and $R(x)$.

Comment: The scope of forall x is unclear.